# Why is my personal web site getting visitors at mysterious URLs?

Tags: dns, web-crawler

I recently made an update to my site's visitor logging and when checking that it was working properly noticed that I'm getting visitors at URLs that do not belong to me. I was surprised to even see bots, as the site is not on Google and not linked from anywhere that I know of right now.

My site logs the IP, timestamp, user agent and page address on the site for each visit. For some reason, I'm seeing visitors to the following pages:

- `http://gftjewelry.com/`
- `http://scyimi.com/`
- `http://www.ydf88.dyndns.pro/`

The visitors come from a few different IP addresses and have an assortment of user agents. They look to be mostly spiders. The URLs just resolve to my website.

I've only been using this IP address for a bit less than a month, and one of these URLs is from a dynamic DNS service. The visits have been going on about as long as I've had the site up.

Am I just seeing the aftereffects of other sites that used this IP address? Is there anything I can/should do about this? Are there negative consequences with having these domain names associated with me?

Comment: Welcome to the world wide web.  I have test sites that have never had public visitors, they still get visited regularly by all kinds of weird traffic.  If you don't have a robots.txt file get one, legit traffic will obey... still doesn't stop the yandex bot with Russian IP's tho...

Comment: I'm not certain how that would help - these URLs aren't linked from my website anywhere. It's an issue of someone else having their DNS pointing toward my IP.

Comment: Are you sure this is the address of the site which is being visited, and not the referer URL? My first thought was referer spam - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spam

Comment: That was my first thought,  and part of the reason for my concern,  but the URL resolves to my site and there's no good reference to those sites on Google.

Comment: This would belong on Webmasters, but they have plenty of duplicate questions on the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I just seeing the aftereffects of other sites that used this IP
>   address?

Part of me believes you are seeing traffic based on the IP address’ previous use. Think of it as being no different than getting a “new” phone number but finding out a few days later that some 24 hour locksmith used to have that number; you’re going to get calls all day and night.

But with that said doing some searches of domain name history [via this online tool](http://whoisrequest.org/history/) leads me other conclusions.

For example, using that online tool a historical look at DNS for `scyimi.com` shows only one cluster of DNS servers ever being associated with that address:

```
ns6.ezdnscenter.com
ns5.ezdnscenter.com
ns4.ezdnscenter.com
ns3.ezdnscenter.com
ns2.ezdnscenter.com
ns1.ezdnscenter.com
```

So if I run a [`dig`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dig) from the command line doing a lookup on one of those specific DNS servers for `scyimi.com` like this:

```
dig @ns1.ezdnscenter.com scyimi.com
```

This is the result I get back:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @ns1.ezdnscenter.com scyimi.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 2606
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;scyimi.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
scyimi.com.     28800   IN  A   192.161.50.176

;; Query time: 370 msec
;; SERVER: 113.17.175.134#53(113.17.175.134)
;; WHEN: Sun Dec  7 20:11:46 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 44
```

So yes, some DNS servers are clearly connecting that hostname to that IP.

As for what this means to you? 100% nothing really. The Internet is a big place. And if you do [`whois`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/whois) searches on the DNS hosts above—as well as the original hostnames—you can see them all being owned by some entity in China.

Concerned about how it would impact your site? The reality is it probably won’t mean much of anything. Servers are constantly being probed constantly so it’s no big deal.

But if you are concerned, one step you can do is to ensure your site is being delivered via name-based virtual host setup if you are using Apache for the web serve. And making sure the bare IP address dead-ends to a blank page.

What [Apache does with a name-based virtual host configuration](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) is it binds the Apache web server to the hostname as well as the IP address. So any traffic coming your way would have to explicitly come from someone—or something—making a request to that hostname. Any requests to the IP address would be treated as a separate virtual host. And I like to ensure that the bare IP address on a server just deadens to a blank page.

If you do that, then the traffic coming from those other hostnames would basically fall into that dead end. And legit traffic flows smoothly to your main site. I do this on pretty much all of the high traffic web servers I setup. It makes a difference.

But again, this might not mean much if you are running a low-traffic personal portfolio site. Eventually as you pass your site URL to others, more of that spider/robot traffic will show up anyway… The big difference is now they will be useless visitors to your actual domain.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I've switched back to name-based virtual hosts. I'm not overly concerned about bot traffic and such, the VPS I have is already more than is needed to handle the likely visitors to my site. As long as it isn't going to negatively impact, say, SEO if and when I actually put this on search engines there shouldn't be a problem.